# Change a word with a N repating characters where N = word length

Tags: replace

I have some code that I want to 'censor'. For example, I have secret token in a source code `1f85ez` and I want to replace it with `xxxxxx`

Now I do it with `viwrx` command. Is there way to make such a substitution without visual mode?

Comment: You could make a mapping for it... other possible solutions seem too clunky. (Counting works, e.g. `5rx`, but takes so much time.) What’s wrong with visual mode? You could always write a new operator that replaced whatever was operated on! Then e.g. `yriwx` would do the trick (similar to how surround.vim functions). But again, at this point, what’s wrong with visual mode?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Can't you just `:s/1f85ez/xxxxxx/g` ? What is your particular situation that makes this solution not good enough? Please give us more details, that might help us find the best solution.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble nothing wrong, I guess. Thanks.

Comment: @msb yep, but if you have 60 characters (not 6) it's not a good way to make such a substitution.

Comment: `:exec "s/" . expand("<cword>") . "/" . repeat('x', strlen(expand("<cword>")))`    :p ;)